# Unable to catch a std::runtime_error

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

Maybe I haven't had enough coffee today.  The following program should catch the std::runtime_error and print "i caught the runtime_error", right?

It is not.  This program is not catching the std::runtime_error and is instead printing "why was i unable to catch the runtime_error"?

What am I doing wrong here?  Why am I not catching the std::runtime_error?

This is Clang (see environment info below code).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    try
    {
        throw new std::runtime_error( "a runtime_error was thrown" );
    }
    catch ( const std::runtime_error& e )
    {
        std::cout << "i caught the runtime_error" << std::endl;
    }
    catch ( ... )
    {
        std::cout << "why was i unable to catch the runtime_error?" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Xcode 5.1.1 on OS X 10.9.5

```
comp:~ usrn$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
comp:~ usern$
```

Comment: You should not use `new` here.

Comment: For some reason I thought heap allocating exceptions was required.  I don't know how I got that idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're throwing `new std::runtime_error( "a runtime_error was thrown" );`,

So you're throwing a `std::runtime_error*`.

You probably want to do `throw std::runtime_error("...")`, i.e. throw by value.

Comment: Yep.  That was fast.  Thanks.

Comment: Or better: *Not* throw a heap allocated object. Throw by value, catch by const reference.

Comment: Are you advising they should keep using `new`?

Comment: Not at all, just stating facts. But I probably should clarify :)

Comment: melak47, you should add to the end of your answer a recommendation not to use heap allocated throws.  Thanks!